# My query is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My query is not working which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempCal (
    CategoryId BIGINT
    ,CategoryName NVARCHAR(max)
    ,ElementWeight MONEY
    ,MakingCharges MONEY
    ,GemstoneAttribute NVARCHAR(max)
    ,AlloyAttribute NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Rates MONEY
    )

--insert into #tempCal(CategoryId,CategoryName,ElementWeight,MakingCharges,GemstoneAttribute,AlloyAttribute,Rates)
--values
DECLARE @iterator BIGINT = (
        SELECT max(MstJewelleryProduct.ID)
        FROM MstJewelleryProduct
        )

INSERT INTO #tempCal (
    CategoryId
    ,CategoryName
    ,ElementWeight
    ,MakingCharges
    ,GemstoneAttribute
    ,AlloyAttribute
    ,Rates
    )
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT MstJewelleryProduct.ElementWeight
            ,MstJewelleryProduct.Element_Price
            ,MstJewelleryProduct.MakingCharges
            ,MstJewelleryProduct.GemstoneAttribute
            ,MstJewelleryProduct.AlloyAttribute
            ,MstJewelleryCategory.ID
            ,MstJewelleryCategory.CategoryName
            ,MstRates.Rates
            ,MstJewelleryOffers.OfferAmount
        FROM MstJewelleryProduct
        INNER JOIN MstJewelleryCategory ON MstJewelleryProduct.CategoryID = MstJewelleryCategory.ID
        LEFT JOIN MstRates ON MstJewelleryProduct.CategoryID = MstRates.CategoryId
        LEFT JOIN MstJewelleryOffers ON MstJewelleryProduct.CategoryID = MstJewelleryOffers.ProductCategory
            AND MstJewelleryOffers.IsActive = 1
        WHERE MstJewelleryProduct.IsActive = 1
        )
    )

SELECT *
FROM #tempCal

DROP TABLE #tempCal
```

Comment: Can you please says what's not working ?

Comment: what output are you getting? or an error?

Comment: In the absence of an answerable question, you might want to start with trying to align the values returned in your subquery to the columns defined in the temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the (**Insert** **Into**) is not correct. When you use (**Select**) you do not need to use (**Values**). Please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to check the right syntax.